# List all Blobs and containers of all the storage accounts

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage, azure-storage-account

I'm using the below script to run:

```
$context = Get-AzContext
$storageAccounts = Get-AzResource -ResourceType 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts' 

[System.Collections.ArrayList]$saUsage = New-Object -TypeName System.Collections.ArrayList

 foreach ($storageAccount in $storageAccounts) {

   #list containers
   $containers= Get-AzStorageContainer -ResourceGroupName $storageAccount.ResourceGroupName -StorageAccountName $storageAccount.Name

     if($containers -ne $null){
          foreach($container in $containers){
            $StorageAccountDetails = [ordered]@{
                    SubscriptionName = $context.Subscription.Name
                    SubscrpitionID = $context.Subscription.Id
                    StorageAccountName = $storageAccount.Name
                    ContainerName = $container.Name
                    ResourceGroup = $storageAccount.ResourceGroupName
                    Location = $storageAccount.Location
                    size = $Storage.size
               }
             $saUsage.add((New-Object psobject -Property $StorageAccountDetails))  | Out-Null   
            }     
      }else{
      
        $StorageAccountDetails = [ordered]@{
                SubscriptionName = $context.Subscription.Name
                SubscrpitionID = $context.Subscription.Id
                StorageAccountName = $storageAccount.Name
                ContainerName = $null
                ResourceGroup = $storageAccount.ResourceGroupName
                Location = $storageAccount.Location
                size = $Storage.size      
         }
        $saUsage.add((New-Object psobject -Property $StorageAccountDetails)) | Out-Null
     }     
}
$saUsage
```

But I'm getting an error, Please assist

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Get-AzStorageContainer : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'ResourceGroupName'.
At line:10 char:40
+    $containers= Get-AzStorageContainer -ResourceGroupName $storageAcc ...
+                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-AzStorageContainer], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Storage.Blob.Cmdlet.GetAzureStorageContainerCommand

Comment: Please check the documentation of this Cmdlet here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/get-azstoragecontainer?view=azps-8.2.0.

Comment: I have tried but nothing seems to work

Answer (score 0):

The problem is described in the error message:

```
A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'ResourceGroupName'
```

The cmdlet `Get-AzStorageContainer` does not support this parameter (and also does not suppport the `-StorageAccountName` parameter).

You might want to use the `-Context` parameter. However, this also requires you to use the `Get-AzStorageAccount` cmdlet since `Get-AzResource` does not return the Storage Account Context.

The context contains all relevant properties that are required to connect to the storage account.

```
Name               MemberType Definition
----               ---------- ----------
Equals             Method     bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode        Method     int GetHashCode()
GetType            Method     type GetType()
ToString           Method     string ToString()
BlobEndPoint       Property   string BlobEndPoint {get;}
ConnectionString   Property   string ConnectionString {get;}
Context            Property   Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.Abstractions.IStorageContext Context {get;set;}
EndPointSuffix     Property   string EndPointSuffix {get;}
ExtendedProperties Property   System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary[string,string] ExtendedProperties {get;}
FileEndPoint       Property   string FileEndPoint {get;}
Name               Property   string Name {get;set;}
QueueEndPoint      Property   string QueueEndPoint {get;}
StorageAccount     Property   Microsoft.Azure.Storage.CloudStorageAccount StorageAccount {get;}
StorageAccountName Property   string StorageAccountName {get;set;}
TableEndPoint      Property   string TableEndPoint {get;}
```

This is just for information. Using code along the lines below should solve this.

```
$storageAccounts = Get-AzStorageAccount

foreach ($storageAccount in $storageAccounts) {
    $containers = Get-AzStorageContainer -Context $storageAccount.Context
    # ... continue code
}
```

Please check the corresponding documentation for further details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/get-azstoragecontainer?view=azps-8.2.0

Comment: Get-AzStorageContainer : This request is not authorized to perform this operation.
RequestId:834a9799-f01e-0067-26e5-c1da3d000000
Time:2022-09-06T11:39:47.3942337Z
Status: 403 (This request is not authorized to perform this operation.)
ErrorCode: AuthorizationFailure
Content:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>AuthorizationFailure</Code><Message>This request is not authorized to 
perform this operation.
RequestId:834a9799-f01e-0067-26e5-c1da3d000000
At line:8 char:16
+ ... $containers = Get-AzStorageContainer -Context $storageAccount.Context

Comment: What RBAC role do you have assigned against the storage accounts?

Comment: I'm the Owner of all Resources

Comment: Could be due to Firewall settings on the storage accounts. I had this just today when I was creating containers through terraform but my computer's public IP was not part of the Storage Account network rules. You can try to access a container through the Azure Portal and should see a similar error, maybe with a little more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below python version code.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService
from datetime import datetime
import os.path

account_name='container-name'
container_name ='folder1'
account_key = 'account-key'
prefix_val = 'data'

block_blob_service = BlockBlobService(account_name='%s'%(account_name), account_key='%s'%(account_key))

#block_blob_service.create_container(container_name)
generator = block_blob_service.list_blobs(container_name,prefix="%s"%(prefix_val),timeout=None)
#generator = block_blob_service.list_blobs(container_name)
report_time = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')


Target_file = "/dbfs/ADLSAUDIT/clouderadatalaketransfer/actian.csv" 
print(Target_file)

Target_file = open("%s"%(Target_file), 'w')

for blob in generator:
    
    length = BlockBlobService.get_blob_properties(block_blob_service,container_name,blob.name)
    last_modified = BlockBlobService.get_blob_properties(block_blob_service,container_name,blob.name).properties.last_modified
    file_size = BlockBlobService.get_blob_properties(block_blob_service,container_name,blob.name).properties.content_length
    blob_type = BlockBlobService.get_blob_properties(block_blob_service,container_name,blob.name).properties.blob_type
    if file_size != 0:
       line = account_name+'|'+container_name+'|'+blob.name+'|'+ str(file_size) +'|'+str(last_modified)[:10]+'|'
       print(line)
       Target_file.write(line+'\n')
Target_file.close()
```